# How do I print the next element in a linked list to a CSV file?

Tags: java, string, linked-list, printwriter

I'm making an address book and my program is supposed to save each element in a list to a CSV file. I've gotten everything to work asside from the fact that it will only save 1 line to the file.

```
public static void save(){
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Remixt\\workspace\\2\\AddressBook.csv", "UTF-8");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}
 {
    writer.println(AddressBook.get(getListSize()-1)+"\n");


writer.close();//saves file
}
```

Edit: It will only save the last element to the file. It only shows 1 thing in the file no matter how many times i add something else to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

```
writer.println(AddressBook.get(getListSize()-1)+"\n");
```

you just write the last element of `AddressBook` to the `csv` file, use `for loop`

the following is a sample

```
for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.size(); i++) {
     writer.println(AddressBook.get(i)+"\n");

}
```

at last, you should write file by `append mode`

```
 filename=new FileWriter("printWriter.txt",true);
 writer=new java.io.PrintWriter(filename);
```